# options menu background is translucent

Tags: android, menu, background, transparent

I have the following code for an options menu intended for Android versions starting on 2.3.3

```
private static final int ECHO_MENU_ITEM = 7;
private static final int BEEP_PROMPT_MENU_ITEM = 8;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, ECHO_MENU_ITEM, 0, "Echo");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, BEEP_PROMPT_MENU_ITEM, 1, "Beep Prompt");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
}
```

When I click on the "Menu" button on my Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.4

The menu pops up on the bottom left corner, but it has a translucent background.
How can I make it opaque instead?
I am not using an action bar